# Django is getting static file path when inspect But cannot find the file on location

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here is my URLs of project file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from django.conf import settings

from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('resume.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
urlpatters = urlpatterns + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here is my URL of resume app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.resume,name='resume',)
]
```

Here is my resume models

```
class about(models.Model):
    profile = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Here is my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')


MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'/media/'))
```

This is my Files orientations
[This is my Files orientations in django](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7X6r.png)

Here is my element in chrome where link of image is perfectly found but file is not getting,

[Here is my element in chrome where link of image is perfectly found but file is not getting,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zALo.png)

I am new to django , please use simple terms so I can understand , where I am doing wrong and How can I fix this.
please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your
       INSTALLED_APPS.
2. In your templates, use the static template tag to
       build the URL for the given relative path using the configured
       STATICFILES_STORAGE :-

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static "my_app/example.jpg" %}" alt="My image">
```

path of the image should be ( my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg. ) not in the root of the project . ( in the app ) .

for more info :- 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

Comment: Yes I already added these lines in my templates , I am able to load all the javascipts CSS files as well , but when I am trying to pass images from database then ,  Browser console says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: go to admin site  and  find the url of the image . if the image open check your template .or  you should check your media url . https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0WyY.png .by type uncorrect url . the try to navigate to the image with browser if it run check template .